# How can I show a variable in Bootstrap modal in PHP?

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a `form` that makes a calculation, enter the database and returns the value through an alert.
I would like to replace this `alert` for `modal`.

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="#">
<input type="text" name="alt" id="altura" required><br><br>
<input type="text" name="peso" id="peso" required><br><br> 

<button type="submit" id="Send">Send</button>
 </form>
```

PHP

```
function calcularIMC($altura,$peso){
 $imc = 0;
   if($altura >0 && $peso >0){
     $imc = $peso / ($altura * $altura);
   }

 echo '<script>';
 echo 'alert("'.$imc.'");';
 echo '</script>';
}
```

I tried as follows: 
- Added the `php` after the tag `</html>` code;
- Added the variable responsible for the calculation: `$imc`; 
- I linked the button `Send` with `modal`.

```
<form method="post" action="#">
   <input type="hidden" name="acao" id="acao" value="cadastrar"/>

   <input type="text" name="alt" id="altura" required><br><br>
   <input type="text" name="peso" id="peso" required><br><br>
   <button type="submit" id="Enviar" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Enviar</button>
   </form>

   <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
     <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
       <div class="modal-content">            
      <div class="modal-body">
          <?php echo'.$imc.';?>
         </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>                   
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
<?php
      function calcularIMC($altura,$peso){
    $imc = 0;
    if($altura >0 && $peso >0){
        $imc = $peso / ($altura * $altura);
     }   
    return $imc;
    }
 ?>
```

Thus, when I click on `Send` button (with all the empty fields), it opens the modal and displays the `'.$imc.'` as String.
When I insert the data and click on the button `Send` a dims window (early effect of modal) and quickly back to normal. I believe the `modal` is being called, but some stretch it gives erros and closes.

How can I solve this?

AJAX, top of code:

```
<?php
$imc = false;

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
$imc = calcularImc($_POST['altura'], $_POST['peso']);
}
?>
```

End of `body`

```
<?php
  if ($imc !== false){
    echo "<script>$('#myModal').modal('show');</script>";
  }
?>
```

Would it be this? I tried to add this code, but gave the same result. By submitting the form, the window dims and quickly back to normal.

---------------------------------UPDATED / I MANAGED TO DO THAT I WANTED-------------------------------

```
<form method="post" action="#">
<input type="text" name="alt" id="altura" required><br><br>
<input type="text" name="peso" id="peso" required><br><br> 

<button type="submit" id="Send" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Send</button>
</form>

<?php

$imc = false;

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
$imc = calcularImc($_POST['altura'], $_POST['peso']);
}
?>


<?php
  if ($imc !== false){
    echo '<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>';
    echo '<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>';
    echo "<script>$('#myModal').modal('show');</script>";
  }
?>
</body>
</html>

function calcularIMC($altura,$peso){

 $imc = 0;
     if($altura >0 && $peso >0){
      $imc = $peso / ($altura * $altura);
     }

echo '<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">';

echo $imc;     // RESULT OF CALC MODAL INSIDE        

echo '</div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>';
} 
?>
```

Comment: Where do you call calcularIMC and where do you set $imc? Your syntax is incorrect. If you want to print a variable just use `<?php echo $imc; ?>`

Comment: I want call calcularIMC inside of `modal`. $imc is declared in calcularIMC. Since my syntax is wrong, how I can fix? Do you can help me?

Comment: You can't call php code on a page already rendered. So you would either have to submit the form and check on the page if the form is submitted and automatically open the model, or you would have to make a AJAX request to the server to execute your PHP code. If you don't want to refresh the page, lookup AJAX.

Comment: @Laurens I added a code Ajax, please look and tell me if it is more or less this kind of code? When I submitting the form, the window dims and quickly back to normal.

Comment: It is not AJAX, as you are just refreshing the page, so its a normal post form, which is also good. I will check your code for errors in a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POST Method:

```
<?php
function calcularIMC($altura,$peso){
   $imc = 0;
   if($altura >0 && $peso >0){
     $imc = $peso / ($altura * $altura);
   }
   return $imc;
}
$imc = "";
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $imc = calcularImc($_POST['alt'], $_POST['peso']);
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
<form method="post" action="#">
   <input type="hidden" name="acao" id="acao" value="cadastrar"/>

   <input type="text" name="alt" id="altura" required><br><br>
   <input type="text" name="peso" id="peso" required><br><br>
   <button type="submit" id="Send">Send</button>
   </form>

   <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
     <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
       <div class="modal-content">            
      <div class="modal-body">
          <?php echo $imc;?>
         </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>                   
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Errors you made:

- Addres altura as $_POST['altura'] instead of $_POST['alt'] (as its name attribute is alt)
- You started your modal.show script before the page was loaded. So the modal might not exist yet. Wrap it in `$(window).load(function(){})`
- Printed the variable in the wrong way: `echo'.$imc.'` should have been `echo $imc;`

Even nicer would be to use AJAX. Then you don't have to refresh the page. If you want to do that, lookup AJAX. You could also avoid using PHP. @AceWebDesign Answer explains nicely how this can be done without PHP.

Comment: I was using a structure similar to yours, but your answer "cleared my mind." Thank you! 

As I said, I wanted the answer to be displayed within the `modal`. As it was before, even if all the fields were blank I could open the `modal` perfectly. I put the modal code inside the php and solved it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery for this.
instead of

```
 echo '<script>';
 echo 'alert("'.$imc.'");';
 echo '</script>';
```

You could use this on the page. It may need some tweaking as it was quick and rough, and the modal was a little rusty.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>


<body>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form method="post" action="#">
    <input type="hidden" name="acao" id="acao" value="cadastrar"/>

    <input type="text" name="alt" id="altura" required><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="peso" id="peso" required><br><br>
    <button type="submit" id="Enviar" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Enviar</button>
</form>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).off("click", ".btn-default").on( "click", ".btn-default", function(e) {
            var altura = $('#altura').val();
            var peso = $('#peso').val();
            var imc =0;
            if (altura > 0 )
            {
                var imc = peso / (altura * altura);
            }
            $(".modal-body").html(imc);
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code has other functions and issue code integration I will do with `php`. But, is code that maybe I can use in the future. Thanks!